# self-Whitney sum of the canonical vector bundle on Grassmannians

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $G_{k}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be the Grassmannian manifold consisting of $k$-subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^N$. There is a canonical $k$-dimensional vector bundle 
$$
\gamma_{k,N}: \mathbb{R}^k\longrightarrow E(\gamma_{k,N})\longrightarrow G_k(\mathbb{R}^N)
$$
where 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(\gamma_{k,N})&=&\{(V,v)\mid V\in G_k(\mathbb{R}^N), v\in V\}
\\&=&V_k(\mathbb{R}^N)\times_{GL(k)}\mathbb{R}^k.
\end{eqnarray*}
Here $V_k(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is the Stiefel manifold consisting of $k$-tuples or linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$.
In particular, when $k=1$, we have the canonical Hopf line bundle
$$
\gamma_{1,N}: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow S^N\times_{ \mathbb{Z}/2} \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^N.
$$

**Question.**  Are there references/results for the order (the order of a vector bundle is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that the $n$-fold self-Whitney sum of the vector bundle is trivial) of $\gamma_{k,N}$?

In the paper [*Vector fields on spheres,*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/adams2.pdf) J.F. Adams, 1962, Theorem 7.4, it is proved 
$$
\text{order}(\gamma_{1,N})=2^{\phi(N)}
$$
where $\phi(N)$ is the number of positive integers no larger than $N$ and  congruent to $0,1,2,4$ mod $8$. I want to find references/generalizations to $\gamma_{k,N}$.

Comment: For $k \ge 2$, you have the first Pontryagin class $p_1=-c_2(\gamma_{k,N}\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C)$. If $N$ is sufficiently large, the bundle $\gamma_{k,N}$ is universal for rank $k$ bundles over CW-spaces of dimension $4$. But then the order must be $\infty$.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Thanks, Prof. Goette! I modified my question and I want to consider the order of another vector bundle http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227230/self-whitney-sum-of-the-canonical-vector-bundle-on-stiefel-manifolds. Could you give more help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand the comment above a bit. Consider the tautological bundle $\tau\to\mathbb C P^2$. It is complex and has total Chern class $c(\tau)=1+a$, where $a\in H^2(\mathbb C P^2)$ generates the cohomology ring of $\mathbb C P^2$. Viewed as a real bundle, it has $$p_1(\tau_{\mathbb R})=-c_2(\tau\oplus\bar\tau)=-c_1(\tau)c_1(\bar\tau)=a^2$$ because $\tau_{\mathbb R}\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C\cong \tau\oplus\bar\tau$. But $a^2$ generates $H^4(\mathbb C P^2)\cong\mathbb Z$, so $\tau_{\mathbb R}$ has order $\infty$.

So, as soon as $N_0$ is large enough such that $G_k(\mathbb R^{N_0})$ classifies $\tau_{\mathbb R}$,
you get order $\infty$ for $\gamma_{2,N_0}$. By adding a trivial bundle to $\tau$, the same argument shows that the order of $\gamma_{2+n,N_0+n}$ is $\infty$ as well.